# How to make jQuery scroll down on click. My doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Unfortunately, this script doesn't work for me. I know there is some mistake... Please help

I tried to use jquery... I didn't work well for me

```js
$(function() {
  $(".for_home-title a").on('click', function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<div class="for_home-title col-xs-5 col-sm-9 col-md-4">
  <h2>ТАРИФЫ НА ИНТЕРНЕТ И ТЕЛЕВИДЕНИЕ</h2>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs list-group" id="myTabMD" role="tablist">

    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light active">
      <a class="nav-link list-group-item-action" id="order_fast-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" href="#order_fast-md" role="tab" aria-selected="true">В сети</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
      <a class="nav-link list-group-item-action" id="router_gift-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" href="#router_gift-md" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Дарим роутер</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
      <a class="nav-link list-group-item-action" id="help-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" href="#help-md" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Помоги котятам</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
      <a class="nav-link list-group-item-action" id="digital_tv-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" href="#digital_tv-md" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Цифровое ТВ</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
      <a class="nav-link list-group-item-action" id="cabel_tv-tab-md" data-toggle="tab" href="#cabel_tv-md" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Кабельное ТВ</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>



<div class="tab-content col-md-4" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="spread tab-pane fade show active" id="order_fast-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="order_fast-tab-md">
    <ul class="rounded-bg">
      <li><span>Скорость Интернета:</span>до 100 Мбит/с</li>
      <li><span>Оплата:</span>первые 6 месяцев 150 руб/мес далее 250 руб/мес</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="spread tab-pane fade" id="router_gift-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="router_gift-tab-md">
    <ul class="rounded-bg">
      <li><span>Скорость Интернета:</span>до 100 Мбит/с</li>
      <li><span>Оплата:</span>350 руб/мес, Wi-Fi роутер в пользование</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="spread tab-pane fade" id="help-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="help-tab-md">
    <ul class="rounded-bg">
      <li><span>Скорость Интернета:</span>до 100 Мбит/с</li>
      <li><span>Оплата:</span> 375 руб/мес. Wi-fi роутер в пользование. 25 руб с каждой абонентской платы поступает на счет «Котодом»</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="spread tab-pane fade" id="digital_tv-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="digital_tv-tab-md">
    <ul class="rounded-bg">
      <li><span>Скорость Интернета:</span>до 100 Мбит/с</li>
      <li><span>Оплата:</span>первые 12 месяцев 100 руб/мес далее 2500 руб/мес. При подключение интернета (около 200 каналов, оплата 300 руб/мес)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cabel-tv spread tab-pane fade" id="cabel_tv-md" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="cabel_tv-tab-md">
    <ul class="rounded-bg">
      <li><span>Скорость Интернета:</span>до 100 Мбит/с</li>
      <li><span>Оплата:</span>150 руб/мес. Около 200 каналов</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  I've moved your html into the question; in future when you need to make changes to your question you can do it by editing the question instead of by posting the update as an answer.

Comment: (That said, though, I believe your script is working correctly, there just isn't enough padding at the bottom of the page to let the scrolling happen.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Daniel. But what if I just don't need any padding there ? It should be scrolling down only in screens smaller than 768px

Comment: You can see in the code snippet in your question that it does scroll down correctly on small screens; when the screen is large enough that the bottom of the page is already visible, no scrolling will happen.  So if you want the scroll to happen, you do need extra padding.